# grid traversal question

Tags: algorithm, grid, traversal, spiral

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looping in a spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral)

Given a grid of any height and width, write an algorithm to traverse it in a spiral. (Starting at the top left and ending in the middle) without passing over previously visited nodes. Without using nested loops.

Comment: Wow, did you copy and paste that right out of your homework?

Comment: no. my friend needs help. I know how to do it in two nested for loops. Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral

Comment: Do you know the height and width of the grid in advance?

Comment: -1 for "no. my friend needs help"

Comment: Regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral: That answer started at the center and worked outward, assumes odd dimensions, and has an... interesting... way of handling grids where width and height are not equal.

Answer (score -2):

it should be done using one for loop and starting from bottom left, I'am in that coarse

Comment: This answer is quite vague and incomplete. Please format your answers better.