# Get spiral index from location in 1d, 3d

Tags: algorithm

Based on a known {x,y,z,...} coordinate, I'm looking for the index of a location. A 2-dimensional (2d) solution, is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970134/get-spiral-index-from-location).
I'm now trying to extend this to two other dimensions: 1d and 3d (and possibly to generalize to higher dimensions).

For 1d, I ended up with the following algorithm (Matlab code), where the walk alternates between the right and left side of the axis:

```
n = 20; %number of values
X = -n/2:n/2; %X values (1d)

%we want 'p' the index of the location:
for i=1:numel(X)
    if(X(i) > 0)
        p(i) = 2*X(i)-1;
    else
        p(i) = -2*X(i);
    end
end
```

resulting in the following indexes:
[image]

However, I have difficulties in vizualizing how the indexation should takes place in 3d (i.e. how the index walks through the nodes in 3d). I'm primarily interested in a C/C++ solution but any other language is fine.

**EDIT**
Reflecting ***@Spektre*** comments and suggestions: I aim at finding the indexes of a set of 3d coordinates {x,y,z}. This can be seen as a way to map the 3d coordinates into a set of indexes (1d). The spiral provides a convenient way to perform such a task in 2d, but cannot be extended in 3d.

Comment: well your main problem is that you use term "spiral" which is 2D object/construct... and I do not think it can be expanded into different dimension (and still be called spiral). Even your 1D is questionalble (better call it 1D cut through spiral instead). So to move to 3D or more you would need to first determine what the stuff should do: (cover (hyper)volume with single polyline/curve what shape (curved,rectangular) ? However that would not be spiral more like coil of spirals on hyperspheres/hypercubes with increasing radius/size...

Comment: Also you might want to investigate **space filling curves** like [2D/3D hilbert curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488348/2521214) thre probably is something similar if not the same as you want to achieve... So what pattern/shape in 3D you want can you describe more?

Comment: @Spektre Thank you for the interesting link. Distributing the point evenly on an hypersphere could possibly solve my issue. However, I aim at finding the inverse problem: i.e. finding the index instead of the position {x,y,z,...}), and I need this ot be fast. To be more precise, I would like to map a set of coordinates {x,y,z,...} into 1D and the spiral index provides a convenient (and quite fast) solution in 2D. However, as you stated, this cannot be extended to nD, I will reflect this in the topic.

Comment: @Spektre Really interesting replies! i will go for cube_map it really sounds to fit my problem! Thank you I will mark your answer when ready.

Comment: I moved the comments into answer and add some more stuff ... I also cleared out the comments a bit... Also I think you should google up **butterfly shuffling** and **bit-reversal of index/address** ... I got the feeling they could ease up the conversion into your pattern without any goniometrics (but its just feeling so I might be wrong)

Comment: @Spektre Not sure to understand, I want the index from point n-d location, that is indicated in the title (i'm not looking for the location from the index, that is, the reverse of my question).

Comment: Aaah my bed I misreaded your comment ...`However, I aim at finding the inverse problem: i.e. finding the index instead of the position {x,y,z,...}` was seeing just `finding the index instead of the position {x,y,z,...}` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as you chose line/square/cube like coil of screws to fill your 1D/2D/3D space like this:

[image: 1D/2D/3D preview]

I would:

1. **Implement `line/square/cube` maps**

   These will map between 1D index `ix` and coordinate for known "radius". It will be similar to this:

   - [template<class T,int N> class cube_map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284464/2521214)

   See the member functions: `ix2dir` and `dir2ix` which maps between index and direction vector. No need to store the surface data you just need these conversion functions. However you need to tweak them so the order of points/indexes represent the pattern you want... in 1D,2D is easy but for 3D I would chose something like surface spiral on cube similar to this:

   - [How to distribute points evenly on the surface of hyperspheres in higher dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57240140/2521214)

   Do not forget to handle even and odd screws in 3D differently (mirror) so screws join at correct locations...

   Just to be complete the cube map is like single screw in your 3D system it holds the surface of a cube and can convert between direction vector dir and 1D index ix back and forward. Its used to speed up algorithms in both graphics and geometry ... I think its first use was for Bump Mapping fast vector normalizations. By using cube_map you can do analogy in any dimensionality even 2D,1D easily you just use square_map and Line_map instead without any algo changes. I have tested it on OBB 2D/3D after conversion to cube/square maps the algo stayed the same just the vectors had different number of coordinates (without them the algos where very different).
2. **create/derive equation/LUT that describes how many points which radius covers (inside screws included)**

   So function that returns number of points that are in coil of `r` screws together. It will be a series so the equation should be derivable/inferable easily. Let call this:

   ```
   points = volume(r);
   ```
3. **now conversion `ix -> (x,y,z...)`**

   first find which radius `r` your `ix` is so:

   ```
   volume(r) <= ix < volume(r+1)
   ```

   simple for loop will do but even better would be **binary search** of `r`. Then convert your `ix` into index `iy` in line/square/cube map:

   ```
   iy = ix-volume(r);
   ```

   Now just use the `ix2dir(iy)` function to obtain your point position...
4. **Reverse conversion `(x,y,z...) -> ix`**

   ```
   r = max(|x|,|y|,|z|,...)
   iy = dir2ix(x,y,z,...)
   ix = volume(r-1) + iy
   ```