# (LUA) Generate a unique number from 2 numbers

Tags: math, lua

I have a grid of tiles each with coordinates such as (-3, 5) or (1, 540) I want to generate a unique seed for each tile but I haven't found a way to do such

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You can index Lua tables with strings like `"(-3,5)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of "pairing function" - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) describes such functions for natural numbers while you need integers including negative ones.

You can enumerate all integer points at coordinate plane in spiral manner

```
       ^   OY
       |
 16 15 14 13 12
 17  4  3  2 11
 18  5  0  1 10 ==> OX
 19  6  7  8  9
 20 21 22 23 24
```

So, for example, point `-2,-2` has index 20

To calculate such index from coordinates, you can use simple algorithm ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970134/get-spiral-index-from-location/9971465#9971465))

```
if y * y >= x * x then begin
  p := 4 * y * y - y - x;
  if y < x then
    p := p - 2 * (y - x)
end
else begin
  p := 4 * x * x - y - x;
  if y < x then
    p := p + 2 *(y - x)
end;
```

You don't ask for reverse mapping, but it is definitely possible (layer number is `(1 + floor(sqrt(p))) / 2` and so on)

To complete: Python function for reverse mapping

```
def ptoxy(p):
    layer = (int(math.sqrt(p)) + 1) // 2   # integer division
    topleft = 4*layer*layer
    if p <= topleft:
        if p <= topleft - 2 * layer:
            return [layer, 3*layer +  p - topleft]
        else:
            return [-layer + topleft - p, layer]
    else:
        if p >= topleft + 2 * layer:
            return [p-topleft - 3*layer, -layer]
        else:
            return [-layer, layer-p + topleft]
```

[and link to quick-made test](https://ideone.com/cL5cVR)

Comment: I believe this would change the index for each point as the grid updates, I need something that would simply take 2 numbers and return some sort of unique value for those 2 numbers.

Comment: Nevermind this may be what I'm looking for

Comment: For limited grid size you can use another methods - for example, if all coordinates are 16-bits signed integers - just combine them in single 32-bit value  (`(x<<16) or y`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a grid of tiles, you may consider that you have a *first tile*, at the top-left corner and a *last tile* at the bottom-right corner.

```
[0] [1] [2]
[3] [4] [5]
[6] [7] [8]
```

But the `[Row:Col]` notation is more handy.

```
[0:0] [0:1] [0:2]
[1:0] [1:1] [1:2]
[2:0] [2:1] [2:2]
```

So you can access the `[Row:Col]` element with the formula:

```
ColumnCount = 3
Element = (Row * ColumnCount) + Col
```

For example `(2:1)` offset in your grid will be `2*3+1` which is `7`.

```
[0:0] [0:1] [0:2]
[1:0] [1:1] [1:2]
[2:0] [2:1] [2:2]
      --v--
     2*3+1 = 7
```

It's simple and each tile will have a unique identifier.

Comment: The grid is infinite and can go negative

Comment: I'm more asking for a way to generate a unique number for any 2 given numbers, positive or negative

Comment: Quick answer: `f = lambda x,y: 2**x * (2 * y + 1)` gives a unique mapping from pairs of nonnegative integers to positive integers, because every positive number `n` has a unique decomposition as a power of 2 (`2**x`) multiplied by an odd number (`2 * y + 1`).

Comment: @Stef But author needs negative values as well

Comment: Your answer is pretty interesting, I upvoted!