# Image Spiral Pixel Search

Tags: python, colors, pixel, spiral

I'm trying to figure out how to do a pixel (color) search from the center and out, in a *spiral* shape.. Not like the normal "left to right pixel search".

So far i've made some simple x-y searches. Using standard PIL. But it was to slow. as the result always seems to be closer to the center (of the image) in my case. The thing is that it's not a square image, so the center position(s) can be 2 or more pixels (not *A* center, but "two"+ pixels centerd), this is where I "loose it".. Can you peeps give me some hints? Im always working from a screenshot PIL-> **ImageGrab.grab()**, using **image.size** to get the image size, and **px=image.getpixel((x, y))** to get the current pixel-location

I'm working with R,G,B-colours: **if px[0] == r and px[1] == g and px[2] == b:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral) for a bunch of different algorithms written in python for iterating over a matrix in a spiral fashion.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick, and it was easy to make fit my needs! :)