# Coordinate Algorithm - Rotate around the center

Tags: java, algorithm, grid, coordinates

By looking at this image I think you will understand my problem pretty well:

*(image removed - url no longer valid, returns advertising now)*

So basically I want a function that takes an object as parameter and gives this object the correct coordinates based on how many objects I've added before.

Let's say I would add all these objects to an array:

```
objectArray[]
```

Each time I add a new object:
    objectArray.add(object)

The `object.x` and `object.y` coordinates will be set based on some algorithm:

```
object.x = ?
object.y = ?
```

(I'm working in Java)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is pretty close to what it sounds like you want: http://stackoverflow.com/q/398299/535275

Answer (score 7):

Here's the closed-form solution that doesn't rely on a loop... I'm not handy with Java, so it's in C#, but it uses basic operations.

```
static void SpiralCalc(int i) {
    i -= 2;
    // Origin coordinates
    int x = 100, y = 100;
    if (i >= 0) {
        int v = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(Math.Sqrt(i + .25) - .5));
        int spiralBaseIndex = v * (v + 1);
        int flipFlop = ((v & 1) << 1) - 1;
        int offset = flipFlop * ((v + 1) >> 1);
        x += offset; y += offset;
        int cornerIndex = spiralBaseIndex + (v + 1);
        if (i < cornerIndex) {
            x -= flipFlop * (i - spiralBaseIndex + 1);
        } else {
            x -= flipFlop * (v + 1);
            y -= flipFlop * (i - cornerIndex + 1);
        }
    }
    // x and y are now populated with coordinates
    Console.WriteLine(i + 2 + "\t" + x + "\t" + y);
}
```

Comment: For a high-performance scenario where you're not accessing the the related objects in a sequential manner, this isn't as bad with some low level optimization on modern processors as you might think -- usually they have a pretty darned good square root approximation that will be as good as you'll practically need with an offset and a truncation.

Comment: FWIW, coordinate rotations (and scalings) can be done cheaply using only the multiplication of complex numbers.  This requires only adds and multiplies (no roots or trig are needed).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I cannot thank you enough Kaganar!