# Algorithm to get spiral position by coordinate

Tags: geometry, algorithm

This question is a reverse of these questions:

- [Find the position nth element of a rectangular tiled spiral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094745/find-the-position-nth-element-of-a-rectangular-tiled-spiral)
- [Coordinate Algorithm - Rotate around the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135823/coordinate-algorithm-rotate-around-the-center/)
- [Looping in a spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral)

Currently I have this code which gets the coordinate of the nth element in a spiral of squares:

```
private int[] getPos(int n) {
    int x = 0, z = 0;
    if (--n >= 0) {
        int v = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n + .25) - 0.5);
        int spiralBaseIndex = v * (v + 1);
        int flipFlop = ((v & 1) << 1) - 1;
        int offset = flipFlop * ((v + 1) >> 1);
        x += offset; z += offset;
        int cornerIndex = spiralBaseIndex + (v + 1);
        if (n < cornerIndex) {
            x -= flipFlop * (n - spiralBaseIndex + 1);
        } else {
            x -= flipFlop * (v + 1);
            z -= flipFlop * (n - cornerIndex + 1);
        }
    }

    return new int[]{x,z};
}
```

Now I need a function that maps the other way, any ideas?

Comment: Technically, you could call getPos(0), getPos(1), ..., until you find your coordinate. I have a feeling that wouldn't be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. On the assumption that your spiral is, in fact, a square spriral, this is simple enough.

First, we can tell which spiral "level" (or which ring) the position will be on by using this:

```
//parameter "position" assumed
int level = 0;
int layerSize = 1;
while(position > layerSize * layerSize) {
  layerSize += 2;
  level++;
}
```

We know this is the case because each spiral puts squares on either side of the previous spiral (that's the +2) and so the level the position is on is going to be in the area of the largest possible square spiral.

At this point you can use getPos to get the position of (layerSize * layerSize + 1) after that, just walk the spiral shape until your position number is reached.