# Cartesian plane spiral algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Consider touring the Cartesian plane spiral. The initial position is (0,0). in the first step you move to (1.0), in the second step (1.1), in step 3 you'll be in the position (0,1), step 4 takes you to (-1.1) and so on. In step 2012: At what coordinate are you arriving?, What will be the cordinate in 2121?

Comment: Please provide some code or ideas you have tried implementing. It's generally looked down on to use SO as a "Please do my entire assignment for me" type of thing.

Comment: Related: [Looping in a spiral](http://stackoverflow.com/q/398299/335858)

Answer (score 1):

To find the nth coordinate ((0,0) is 0th), first take c=floor(sqrt(n)).  If c*c==n, the coordinate is (c,c).  Otherwise, if n-c*c<=2c, the coordinate is (c+c*c-n,c).  Otherwise, if n-c*c<=4c, the coordinate is (-c,3c+c*c-n).  Otherwise, if n-c*c<=6c, the coordinate is (n-c*c-5c,-c).  Otherwise, the coordinate is (c,n-c*c-7c).  Therefore, 2012 is (-29,44), and 2121 is (41,46).  Please write the code yourself, this seems like homework.

Comment: thanks!....in fact i need to implement the algorithm on c++