# Algorithm find number position in snail 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, spiral

I have a 2D array square size.

such as :

```
(3x3)         (4x4)
1 2 3    or   1   2   3   4
8 9 4         12  13  14  5
7 6 5         11  16  15  6
              10  9   8   7
```

I am trying to find a solution to get by giving a `value` and the `array size` the `Y, X position` of the 2D array.

Exemple:

```
>> find_y_x_in_snail(3, 4)
1, 2
# in a 3x3 array, search value 4
return y=1 x=2
```

the only idea i have to create the snail in a 2D array and return the position.. not that great.

I found the opposite algorithm [here](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-write-a-program-that-fills-in-a-two-dimensional-array-in-a-circular-fashion-with-the-integers-from-1-to-N%C2%B2) (first exemple)

Any idea ?

Comment: For the example, how is `y=2, x=1` giving `7`as the answer. I think you want the value of 3rd column and 2nd row, right??

Comment: at `y=2, x=1` for `3x3` isn't the value `14` for the above example ?

Comment: Sorry guys for deleting, i made a mistake. all my apologies. @svasa for me `3x3` is the first exemple and `4x4` the second

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785462/mapping-elements-of-a-matrix-to-its-position-in-its-spiral-order-traversal ?

Comment: גלעד ברקן The opposite, from the value get coordinates

Comment: Can you clarify. It would seem relatively easy to fill the array and then search for the position of the number you want. However are you asking for a function definition that could generalize to arbitrary size arrays and not solve it by brute force search?

Comment: @BradThomas I know, but my first idea was to find this miracle function, and i wasn't able to find it myself. I rather learn the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
def find_y_x_in_snail(n, v):
    r = 0
    span = n
    while v > span:
        v -= span
        r += 1
        span -= r%2
    d, m = divmod(r,4);
    c = n-1-d
    return [d, d+v, c, c-v][m], [d+v-1, c, c-v, d][m] # y, x
```

#### Explanation

***r*** is the number of corners the "snake" needs to take to get to the targetted value.

***span*** is the number of values in the current, straight segment of the snake, i.e. it starts with ***n***, and decreases after the next corner, and again every second next corner.

***d*** is the distance the snake has from the nearest side of the matrix, i.e. the "winding" level.

***m*** indicates which of the 4 sides the segment -- containing the targetted value -- is at:

0: up
   1: right
   2: down
   3: left

Depending on ***m*** a value is taken from a list with 4 expressions, each one tailored for the corresponding side: it defines the ***y*** coordinate. A similar method is applied (but with different expressions) for ***x***.

Comment: In fact I just notice I returned the tuple in the order x, y, while the function name has y_x, so ***I have switched*** the tuple returned in the `return` statement just now.