# Java Spiral Algorithm

Tags: java

I am looking to make an algorithm which puts numbers in a spiral working from coordinates however this is not a normal spiral and hence im having a problem.

the normal spiral:
[image]

I have looked at other questions hand have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral) to make this spiral.

But I need to make a spiral like this:
[image]

This spiral needs to be created in the same was as in the picture BUT it must be able to adapt to any length and any width. It could be square or rectangular in any direction. The coordinates are in the way they are drawn starting from the bottom left.

How would I go about doing this? All that I have found in my searches are spirals which are square and not what im after.

Comment: Start at F and make a stack.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not depends on Java.

1) Start from any point P = (X,Y) and any direction D = (DX,DY), where one of DX or DY is zero and another is +1 or -1. Also, select rotation clockwise or counterclockwise.

2) Then do N steps in given direction.

3) Rotate direction in taken rotation

4) Do M=1 steps in new direction

5) Set N=N+1

6) Then do N steps in given direction.

7) Rotate direction in taken rotation

8) Set M=M=1

9) 6) Then do M steps in given direction.

10) GOTO (5)

This is rough. Check constraints.