# c++ table spiral algorithm output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arraysize;
    cout<<"Size: ";
    cin>>arraysize;
    int a[arraysize][arraysize];
    int couter = 1, stepTop = 0, stepLeft = 1, stepBottom = 0, stepRight = 1;
    for(int iMain = 0; iMain < ((arraysize / 2) + 1); iMain++)
    {
        for(int i = stepTop; i < stepTop + 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = stepTop; j < (arraysize - stepTop); j++)
            {

                a[i][j] = couter;
                couter++;
            }

        }
        stepTop++;

        if(iMain < (arraysize / 2))
        {
            for(int i = stepRight; i <= (arraysize - stepRight - 1); i++)
            {
                for(int j = (arraysize - stepRight); j < (arraysize - stepRight + 1); j++)
                {
                    a[i][j] = couter;
                    couter++;
                }
            }
            stepRight++;

            for(int i = (arraysize - 1 - stepBottom); i >= (arraysize - stepBottom - 1); i--)
            {
                for(int j = (arraysize - 1 - stepBottom); j >= stepBottom; j--)
                {
                    a[i][j] = couter;
                    couter++;
                }
            }
            stepBottom++;

            for(int i = (arraysize - stepLeft - 1); i >= stepLeft; i--)
                {
                for(int j = stepLeft; j < stepLeft; j++)
                {
                    a[i][j] = couter;
                    couter++;
                }
            }
            stepLeft++;
        }
    }


for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < arraysize; j++)
        {
            cout<<setw(arraysize)<<a[i][j];
            cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when the program output the numbers they are like:

```
Size: 6
     1      2      3      4      5      6
2686500     17     18     19     20      7
     1 2686336     27     28     21      8
4651536 2686512     30     29     22      9
     0     26     25     24     23     10
    16     15     14     13     12     11
```

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.577 s
Press any key to continue.

Image http://imgur.com/kjABBWr

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Its doing the spiral but some of the numbers are big like 2686500

Comment: image http://imgur.com/kjABBWr

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: Some of the numbers are too big for this i make 6 by 6 table and some of the numbers are random not from 1 to 30

Comment: 6x6 would make 36 elements and it appears as if 5 of them you never assign a value. Thus what you get in the output is just rubbish. What is the value of your counter when you are finished assigning values? I would bet that it is 31 and not 36, i.e. you are missing some elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral

Comment: I am input size 6 and its starting and finish with some big numbers

Comment: why dont you put the output in a format such that you can see the matrix? I guess then it will be easier to find out what is going on

Comment: I think the best way to find where is the bug is to run it in debug mode and go step by step to see what's append, specially when build the 2D-array

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change : this->`for(int j = stepLeft; j <= stepLeft; j++)` to this: `for(int j = stepLeft-1; j < stepLeft; j++)`

Ideone link: https://ideone.com/kR8nOZ

Comment: Still false as you increase by 2 instead of 1 when you go up.