# How to create 'clustered dotplots' for categorical data?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I wish to create a graphic, like this one from the software called [Fathom](http://fathom.concord.org/).

[image: http://fathom.concord.org/help/HelpFiles/_img331.png]

I have a two-way table of categorical frequency data that I wish to create something like a fluctuation plot, but the key difference is that you can see the individual data points. 
I've tried `ggfluctuation(...)`, `levelplots(...)` and all manner of packages (like `ggplot2`), but with no success. I can find nothing on any forums to help either.

I'd be exceptionally grateful if someone could help direct me to, or create some code, that would achieve my objective.

Comment: Hello Darshan. I'd be very happy to provide some example data, but I'm not sure how best to post it in this forum. Can you suggest the best format for you to take it and run with this request?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, here's a sample data set and I am looking for a plot that has 'set' on the y-axis and 'grade' on the x-axis, with the data in the 'freq' vector driving the number of dots on display.

sample_data <- data.frame("set"=c("09t0101 TJ","09t0102 MW","09t0201 EH","09t0202 NH"),"grade"=c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4"),"freq"=sample.int(length(0:10),16,replace=TRUE))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is improved version.

```
sample_data = structure(list(set = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("09t0101 TJ", 
"09t0102 MW", "09t0201 EH", "09t0202 NH")), grade = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), freq = c(7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 
4L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("set", 
"grade", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

group = unique(sample_data$set) #Obtain the unique 'set' values for y-axis
max_x = length(unique(sample_data$grade)) #Obtain the maximum number of 'grades' to plot on x-axis
max_y = length(group) #Obtain the maximum number of 'set' to plot on y-axis
pdf(file="plot.pdf",width=8,height=6)
par(mar = c(5, 10, 4, 2)) #c(bottom, left, top, right)
plot(max_x,max_y,xlim=c(0.5,max_x+0.5),ylim=c(0.5,max_y +0.5),pch=NA,xlab="Grades",ylab=NA,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",asp=1) #asp = 1 IMPORTANT
axis(side = 2, at=c(1:length(group)), labels=c(as.vector(group)),las=2)
axis(side = 1, at=c(1:length(unique(sample_data$grade))), labels=c(as.vector(unique(sample_data$grade))))

r = 0.15 #The diameter of circles to be plotted

for (i in 1:length(group)){
a = subset(sample_data,sample_data$set==group[i]) #Subset new data.frame corresponding to first 'set'

for (j in 1:nrow(a)){
matrix_sz = ceiling(sqrt(a$freq[j])) #Determine the size of square matrix that can accomodate all the frequency
matrix_x = matrix(nrow = matrix_sz, ncol = matrix_sz) #Initiate matrix
matrix_y = matrix(nrow = matrix_sz, ncol = matrix_sz) #Initiate matrix
matrix_x[,1] = -1*((matrix_sz/2) - 0.5) #Find out relatve x co-ordinates for first column 
matrix_y[1,] = 1*((matrix_sz/2) - 0.5) #Find out relatve y co-ordinates for first row

# Find out other relative co-ordinates if the size of square matrix is more than 1x1
if (matrix_sz > 1){
for (column in 2:matrix_sz){
matrix_x[,column] = matrix_x[,column - 1] + 1
}
for (row in 2:matrix_sz){
matrix_y[row,] = matrix_y[row-1,] - 1
}
}

#Determine the co-ordinate of the center of the square matrix grid
xx = as.integer(a$grade[j])
yy = i
fq = 1 #To keep track of the corresponding 'freq'

# Plot circles around the center based on relative co-ordinates
for (row in 1:matrix_sz){
for (column in 1:matrix_sz){
if (fq > a$freq[j]){break} #Break if the necessary number of points have been plotted
xx1 = xx + r * matrix_x[row, column]
yy1 = yy + r * matrix_y[row, column]
# points (x = xx1, y = yy1, pch=1)
fq = fq + 1
symbols (x = xx1, y = yy1, circles=c(r/2.25),add =TRUE,inches=FALSE,bg = "gray")
}
}
}
}
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Darshan
That's looking very promising indeed! Thank you for your invested time on this project already. I'm curious to understand why some of the dots are a bit 'adrift' from the main block, such as those for grade 2 for '09t02010 EH'.
I shall look through your code line by line and try to figure out how it does what it does, but it'll take me some time. Any comments that you can add in will be gratefully interpreted!

Comment: Ah! I think I know why some points are adrift. The variable 'theta' is still incrementing in pi/4 steps, when it needs to increase in smaller steps the further out one goes from the 'centre' of the cluster. And this will affect the values that 'hypotenuse' takes as well. I can see how you are trying to plot a 'spiral' of points that snaps to an 'integer grid' of sorts. Clever! Now to just generalise your approach for any size of frequency number and not just those which are less than 10.....

Comment: A bit of searching around on Google for algorithms to generate a square spiral found me this (but none of it is in 'r'). Could this sort of code solution be adapted to avoid having to base the plotting on a circular underlying structure?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral

Comment: Darshan - perfect! Many, many thanks for the improved code, with all the comments. Hopefully this code can help others who are after similar plots. Thank you so very much again. Nevil