# Given a grid, starting at the center and spiraling out, and an Position what is the ID?

Tags: c#, algorithm

**Grid:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  20       | id:  19       | id:  18       | id:  17       | id:  16       |
| pos: (-2, -2) | pos: (-1, -2) | pos: (0, -2)  | pos: (1, -2)  | pos: (2, -2)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  21       | id:  6        | id:  5        | id:  4        | id:  15       |
| pos: (-2, -1) | pos: (-1, -1) | pos: (0, -1)  | pos: (1, -1)  | pos: (2, -1)  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  22       | id:  7        | id:  0        | id:  3        | id:  14       |
| pos: (-2, 0)  | pos: (-1, 0)  | pos: (0, 0)   | pos: (1, 0)   | pos: (2, 0)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  23       | id:  8        | id:  1        | id:  2        | id:  13       |
| pos: (-2, 1)  | pos: (-1, 1)  | pos: (0, 1)   | pos: (1, 1)   | pos: (2, 1)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| id:  24       | id:  9        | id:  10       | id:  11       | id:  12       |
| pos: (-2, 2)  | pos: (-1, 2)  | pos: (0, 2)   | pos: (1, 2)   | pos: (2, 2)   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Code:**

```
public static int IDFromPos(int sectionX, int sectionY) {
    int sectionId = 0;
    if (sectionX < 0 && Mathf.Abs (sectionX) >= Mathf.Abs (sectionY)) {
        sectionId = (int)Mathf.Pow (((-2 * sectionX) + 1), 2) - 1 - (-sectionX - sectionY);
    } else if (sectionX > 0 && Mathf.Abs (sectionX) >= Mathf.Abs (sectionY)) {
        sectionId = (int)Mathf.Pow (((2 * sectionX) + 1), 2) - 1 - (4 * sectionX) - (-sectionX - sectionY);
    } else if (sectionY < 0) {
        sectionId = (int)Mathf.Pow (((-2 * sectionY) + 1), 2) - 1 - (2 * sectionY) - (-sectionY + sectionX);
    } else {
        sectionId = (int)Mathf.Pow ((2 * (sectionY - 1) + 1), 2) + (sectionY - 1 + sectionX);
    }

    return sectionId;
}
```

**Test**

```
IDFromPos(-2, -2) = 20
IDFromPos(-2, -1) = 21
IDFromPos(-2, 0) = 22
IDFromPos(-2, 1) = 23
IDFromPos(-2, 2) = 24
IDFromPos(-1, -2) = 27 (should be 19)
IDFromPos(-1, -1) = 6
IDFromPos(-1, 0) = 7
IDFromPos(0, 0) = 0
IDFromPos(0, 1) = 1
IDFromPos(0, 2) = 10
IDFromPos(1, 0) = 5  (should be 3)
IDFromPos(1, 1) = 6  (should be 2)
IDFromPos(1, 2) = 11
IDFromPos(2, 0) = 18 (should be 14)
IDFromPos(2, 1) = 19 (should be 13)
IDFromPos(2, 2) = 20 (should be 12)
```

I've been staring at this for way to long. I can't see my error(s). Given the `(x,y)` position what is `id`? What is wrong with this function?

*The grid positions are not normal so please look close. -,- is top left, +,+ is bottom right.*

Comment: I don't quite get what is your question.

Comment: @SeM - I added a few more test & what they should be. I'l just trying to get the `id` for a given `x,y` position

Comment: Would a mapping table be an option?

Comment: @richej - no. The grid is just an example. its size isn't set and can be large.

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral

Comment: Is this some sort of test or interview question?

Comment: @SeM - no, its just part of a side project I'm playing around with. I have a job already that I enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

The calculations inside the second and the third `else if` are wrong. In the second, the last subtraction should actually be an addition. In the third, the middle subtraction should be an addition.

```
// ...
} else if(sectionX > 0 && Mathf.Abs(sectionX) >= Mathf.Abs(sectionY)) {
    sectionId = (int)Mathf.Pow(((2 * sectionX) + 1), 2) - 1 - (4 * sectionX) + (-sectionX - sectionY);
} else if(sectionY < 0) {
    sectionId = (int)Mathf.Pow(((-2 * sectionY) + 1), 2) - 1 + (2 * sectionY) - (-sectionY + sectionX);
}
// ...
```

This fixes all your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Divide whole plane into four segments by diagonals and form result for every segment:

```
x * x >= y * y, x >= 0:
   id = 4 * x * x - x - y
x * x >= y * y, x < 0:
   id = 4 * x * x - 3 * x + y
y * y < x * x, y >= 0:
   id = 4 * y * y - 3 * y + x
y * y < x * x, y < 0:
   id = 4 * y * y - y - x

id(2,1) = 16 - 2 - 1 = 12
id(2,-1) = 16 - 2 + 1 = 15
id(-2,1) = 16 + 6 + 1= 23
id(-1, -2) = 16 + 2 + 1= 19
id(-1, 2) = 16  - 6 - 1= 9
```