# Coordinates for clockwise outwards spiral

Tags: haskell, recursion, spiral

I'm trying to make what I think is called an Ulam spiral using Haskell.
It needs to go outwards in a clockwise rotation:

```
   6 - 7 - 8 - 9
   |           |
   5   0 - 1   10
   |       |   |
   4 - 3 - 2   11
               |
 ..15- 14- 13- 12
```

For each step I'm trying to create coordinates, the function would be given a number and return spiral coordinates to the length of input number eg:

```
mkSpiral 9
> [(0,0),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1)]
```

```
(-1, 1) - (0, 1) - (1, 1)
   |        
(-1, 0)   (0, 0) - (1, 0)
   |                 |
(-1,-1) - (0,-1) - (1,-1)
```

I've seen [Looping in a spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947447) solution, but this goes counter-clockwise and it's inputs need to the size of the matrix.

I also found [this](https://github.com/turanct/advent2017/blob/6577a3cce7207de990ba1c565a9dc9427af18e9e/src/Day3.hs#L4-L25) code which does what I need but it seems to go counterclock-wise, stepping up rather than stepping right then clockwise :(

```
type Spiral = Int
type Coordinate = (Int, Int)

-- number of squares on each side of the spiral
sideSquares :: Spiral -> Int
sideSquares sp = (sp * 2) - 1

-- the coordinates for all squares in the given spiral
coordinatesForSpiral :: Spiral -> [Coordinate]
coordinatesForSpiral 1 = [(0, 0)]
coordinatesForSpiral sp = [(0, 0)] ++ right ++ top ++ left ++ bottom
  where fixed = sp - 1
        sides = sideSquares sp - 1
        right = [(x, y) | x <- [fixed], y <- take sides [-1*(fixed-1)..]]
        top = [(x, y) | x <- reverse (take sides [-1*fixed..]), y <- [fixed]]
        left = [(x, y) | x <- [-1*fixed], y <- reverse(take sides [-1*fixed..])]
        bottom = [(x, y) | x <- take sides [-1*fixed+1..], y <- [-1*fixed]]

-- an endless list of coordinates (the complete spiral)
mkSpiral :: Int -> [Coordinate]
mkSpiral x = take x endlessSpiral

endlessSpiral :: [Coordinate]
endlessSpiral = endlessSpiral' 1

endlessSpiral' start = coordinatesForSpiral start ++ endlessSpiral' (start + 1)
```

After much experimentation I can't seem to change the rotation or starting step direction, could someone point me in the right way or a solution that doesn't use list comprehension as I find them tricky to decode?

Comment: Hint: what do you need to change a spiral to go from counter-clockwise to clockwise?

Comment: First I would try writing down in English and/or maths what the sequence of coordinates should be or how you would produce it.  Once you have that you've got something you can translate into code.

Comment: it's to go clockwise, I've just been given a great solution on the FP slack channel so I may post that here if OP doesn't get the time :)

Comment: Side note: an _Ulam spiral_ refers specifically to [a spiral highlighting the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral), whether clockwise or anticlockwise. The examples on Wikipedia all seem to be anticlockwise though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first take a look at how the directions of a spiral are looking:

```
R D L L U U R R R D D D L L L L U U U U ....
```

We can split this in sequences like:

```
      n times       n+1 times
       _^_           __^__
      /   \         /     \
R … R D … D L L … L U U … U
\_ _/       \__ __/
  v            v
n times     n+1 times
```

We can repeat that, each time incrementing `n` by two, like:

```
data Dir = R | D | L | U

spiralSeq :: Int -> [Dir]
spiralSeq n = rn R ++ rn D ++ rn1 L ++ rn1 U
    where rn = replicate n
          rn1 = replicate (n + 1)

spiral :: [Dir]
spiral = concatMap spiralSeq [1, 3..]
```

Now we can use `Dir` here to calculate the next coordinate, like:

```
move :: (Int, Int) -> Dir -> (Int, Int)
move (x, y) = go
    where go R = (x+1, y)
          go D = (x, y-1)
          go L = (x-1, y)
          go U = (x, y+1)
```

We can use [**`scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) to generate the points, like:

```
spiralPos :: [(Int, Int)]
spiralPos = scanl move (0,0) spiral
```

This will yield an infinite list of coordinates for the clockwise spiral. We can use [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) to take the first *k* items:

```
Prelude> take 9 spiralPos
[(0,0),(1,0),(1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, glad this explained `rn R ++ rn D ++ rn1 L ++ rn1 U` as mentally that threw me as to how that was working. Also splitting out the `move` conceptually helped a lot.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Why do you split `move` out into an auxilliary function `go`? Are there any advantages to this approach as opposed to doing it in one function like in my own answer?

Comment: @bradm: I do not really like writing `(x, y)` a lot of times :), so no, it is more minimizing work :)

Answer (score 2):

The idea with the following solution is that instead of trying to generate the coordinates directly, we’ll look at the *directions* from one point to the next. If you do that, you’ll notice that starting from the first point, we go 1× right, 1× down, 2× left, 2× up, 3× right, 3× down, 4× left… These can then be seperated into the *direction* and the *number of times repeated*:

```
direction: > v < ^ > v < …
   # reps: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 …
```

And this actually gives us two really straightforward patterns! The directions just rotate `>` to `v` to `<` to `^` to `>`, while the # of reps goes up by 1 every 2 times. Once we’ve made two infinite lists with these patterns, they can be combined together to get an overall list of directions `>v<<^^>>>vvv<<<<…`, which can then be iterated over to get the coordinate values.

Now, I’ve always thought that just giving someone a bunch of code as the solution is not the best way to learn, so I would *highly* encourage you to try implementing the above idea yourself before looking at my solution below.

---

Welcome back (if you did try to implement it yourself). Now: onto my own solution. First I define a `Stream` data type for an infinite stream:

```hs
data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a) deriving (Show)
```

Strictly speaking, I don’t *need* streams for this; Haskell’s predefined lists are perfectly adequate for this task. But I happen to like streams, and they make some of the pattern matching a bit easier (because I don’t have to deal with the empty list).

Next, I define a type for directions, as well as a function specifying how they interact with points:

```hs
-- Note: I can’t use plain Left and Right
-- since they conflict with constructors
-- of the ‘Either’ data type
data Dir = LeftDir | RightDir | Up | Down deriving (Show)

type Point = (Int, Int)

move :: Dir -> Point -> Point
move LeftDir (x,y)  = (x-1,y)
move RightDir (x,y) = (x+1, y)
move Up (x,y)       = (x,y+1)
move Down (x,y)     = (x,y-1)
```

Now I go on to the problem itself. I’ll define two streams — one for the directions, and one for the number of repetitions of each direction:

```hs
dirStream :: Stream Dir
dirStream = Stream RightDir $ Stream Down $ Stream LeftDir $ Stream Up dirVals

numRepsStream :: Stream Int
numRepsStream = go 1
  where
    go n = Stream n $ Stream n $ go (n+1)
```

At this point we’ll need a function for replicating each element of a stream a specific number of times:

```hs
replicateS :: Stream Int -> Stream a -> Stream a
replicateS (Stream n ns) (Stream a as) = conss (replicate n a) $ replicateS ns as
  where
    -- add more than one element to the beginning of a stream
    conss :: [a] -> Stream a -> Stream a
    conss [] s = s
    conss (x:xs) s = Stream x $ appends xs s
```

This gives `replicateS dirStream numRepsStream` for the stream of directions. Now we just need a function to convert those directions to coordinates, and we’ve solved the problem:

```hs
integrate :: Stream Dir -> Stream Point
integrate = go (0,0)
  where
    go p (Stream d ds) = Stream p (go (move d p) ds)

spiral :: Stream Point
spiral = integrate $ replicateS numRepsStream dirStream
```

Unfortunately, it’s somewhat inconvenient to print an infinite stream, so the following function is useful for debugging and printing purposes:

```hs
takeS :: Int -> Stream a -> [a]
takeS 0 _ = []; takeS n (Stream x xs) = x : (takeS (n-1) xs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, really cool seeing an answer using the concept of Streams and how each stage was achieved :)

Comment: You’re welcome @cmdv! Streams aren’t really too interesting as far as I know — they’re just lists without the `[]` constructor, which makes some of the pattern matching a bit easier. I also had a look at `@WillemVanOnsem’s other answer to this question, and it looks like he used the same idea as my solution, but he did it much simpler — a reminder that building a solution up from simple combinators isn’t necessarily better than direct recursion!